# R: perfect smoothing curve

Tags: r, graphics

I am trying to fit smooth curve to my dataset; is there is any better smoothing curve than I produced using the following codes:

```
x <- seq(1, 10, 0.5)
y <- c(1, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 2.1,
       2.2, 2.2, 2.4, 3.1, 3.3,
        3.7, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 2.4,
        1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.4)
lo <- loess(y~x)
plot(x,y)
xv <- seq(min(x),max(x), (max(x) - min(x))/1000000)
lines(xv, predict(lo,xv), col='blue', lwd=1)
```

EDITS:

I do not intend to produce good looking (not necessary)
I want show a smoothed trend ....
I am not concerned with associated model formula ....I do need to recover formula

Comment: what do you mean by better? anyway that question seems to be more appropriate for stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: plotting a million smoothed points (you could use `seq(min(x),max(x),length.out=1e6)`) seems like overkill for smoothing between 19 points ...

Comment: perfect means more fit to points. I tried less than 1e6 but could not approach to best fit....I am looking for alternative to loess, if that can fit the curve more closer.

Comment: if better means better looking, you might want to look at ggplot2's smoothing geom: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_smooth.html

Comment: i do not mean perfect means good looking (indeed is point to plot), but closer to the observed datapoints

Comment: @John, as you wrote "perfect means more fit to points", be aware, that  fitting 19-degree polynomial via lm(), will precisely fit all your 19 points. But I do believe you will not like this curve. If you solve regression problem, than in short: to answer your question we need more data. It is normal, that fitting loess() to 19 points you don't get small residuals, as in fact there is too little data. anyway take a look to some other regression models: lm(), glm()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As posed, the question is almost meaningless.  There is no such thing as a "best" line of fit, since "best" depends on the objectives of your study.  It is fairly trivial to generate a smoothed line to fit through every single point of data (e.g. a 18th order polynomial will fit your data perfectly, but will most likely be quite meaningless).

That said, you can specify the amount of **smoothness** of a `loess` model by changing the `span` argument.  The larger the value of span, the smoother the curve, the smaller the value of span, the more it will fit each point:

Here is a plot with the value `span=0.25`:

```
x <- seq(1, 10, 0.5)
y <- c(1, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 2.1,
    2.2, 2.2, 2.4, 3.1, 3.3,
    3.7, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 2.4,
    1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.4)

xl <- seq(1, 10, 0.125)
plot(x, y)
lines(xl, predict(loess(y~x, span=0.25), newdata=xl))
```

[image]

---

An alternative approach is to fit splines through your data.  A spline is constrained to pass through each point (whereas a smoother such as `lowess` may not.)

```
spl <- smooth.spline(x, y)
plot(x, y)
lines(predict(spl, xl))
```

[image]

Comment: this gives me my answer, probably my question is blunt as you suggested ...thanks for the answer and guess to the answer

Comment: I've also added an alternative approach using splines which might be useful in your case.

Answer (score 4):

You've got 19 points, so a polynomial up to X^18 will bullseye each of your points:

```
> xl=seq(0,10,len=100)
> p=lm(y~poly(x,18))
> plot(x,y)
> lines(xl,predict(p,newdata=data.frame(x=xl)))
```

BUT that's ignoring what statistics is all about. Its about acknowledging that curves won't fit through points. Its about finding a model with a small number of parameters that explains as much as it can about the data, and leaves only noise. Its not about spearing your points with a curve - a curve so drawn has very little meaning between the data points.

Answer (score 4):

I think perhaps you're looking for an *interpolated* smooth line, which in the case of R is probably most easily accomplished by fitting an interpolation spline?  As the other answers discuss, that's not what statistical fitting is about, but there are many contexts where you want a smooth interpolated curve -- I think your terminology may have thrown people off.

Splines are more numerically stable than polynomials.

```
x <- seq(1, 10, 0.5)
y <- c(1, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 2.1,
    2.2, 2.2, 2.4, 3.1, 3.3,
    3.7, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 2.4,
    1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.4)

library(splines)

isp <- interpSpline(x,y)

xvec <- seq(min(x),max(x),length=200)  ## x values for prediction

png("isp.png")
plot(x,y)
## predict() produces a list with x and y components
lines(predict(isp,xvec),col="red")
dev.off()
```

[image]