# Indefinite Integral in R

Tags: r

I am looking to calculate the indefinite integral of an equation.

I have data from an accelerometer feed into R through a visual C program, and from there it was simple enough to come up with an equation to represent the acceleration curve. That is all well in good, however i need to calculate the impact velocity as well. From my understanding from the good ol' highschool days, the indefinite integral of my acceleration curve will yield the the equation for the velocity.

I know it is easy enough to perform numerical integration with the `integrate()` function, is there anything which is comparable for an indefinite integral?

Comment: If you mean a *symbolic* indefinite integral, then no. (But there are interfaces e.g. to Yacas ["yet another computer algebra system"] that might do it.)  On the other hand, it seems to me that all numerical integration is in some sense definite (i.e. to get an answer you have to specify the limits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the NA's you mention are informative in the sense of indicating no acceleration input then they should be replace by zeros. Let's assume you have the data in `acc.vec` and the device recorded at a rate of `rec_per_sec`:

```
acc.vec[is.na(ac.vec)] <- 0
vel.vec <- cumsum(acc.vec)/recs_per_sec
```

I do not think constructing a best fit curve is going to improve your accuracy in this instance. To plot velocity versus time:

```
plot(1:length(acc.vec)/recs_per_sec, vel.vec, 
       xlab="Seconds", ylab="Integrated Acceleration = Velocity")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! There is no NA's in the data, the input from the accelerometer is always a value, i have never seen a value of 0 come out of my buffer. Thank you for the velocity vs time hint! works great! I had almost given up on it then thought id check back here one more time.

Answer (score 10):

```
library(Ryacas)
x <- Sym("x")
Integrate(sin(x), x)
```

gives

```
expression(-cos(x))
```

An alternative way:

```
yacas("Integrate(x)Sin(x)")
```

You can find the function reference [here](https://yacas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference_manual/index.html)

Comment: In addition to Ryacas, there is the rSymPy package, which uses Python's SymPy for the CAS.

Answer (score 1):

As Ben said, try the Ryacas package for calculating the antiderivative of a function.  But you probably should ask yourself whether you really want to generate a continuous function which only approximates your data in the first place (fitting errors).  I'd stick with numerical integration of your actual data.  Keep in mind the uncertainty in each data point, of course.

Comment: Of course, you could fit a smoothing spline ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953135/r-perfect-smoothing-curve ) and integrate it ...

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input! I was looking for the indefinite integral because i wanted to plot the Velocity - Time graph as well (for visual purposes...does not have to be incredibly accurate). Thanks for the tip on Yacas, but it did not seem to like the function I passed into it (NA's produced by coercion). I suppose i could integrate incrementally across my acceleration function as the velocity at a point is equal to the integration from 0 to that point, however to get a decent curve it would require a substantial number of iterations.