# Ryacas indefinite integral

Tags: r, integral, yacas, ryacas

I am trying to use Ryacas to calculate indefinite integral

```
library(Ryacas)
x <- Sym("x")
Integrate(sin(x), x)
```

but was told the following message.

> Error in Sym("x") : could not find function "Sym"

Can anyone tell me what happened? The version of ryacas is 1.1.3.1. Thanks in advance.

I use the same code as this [Indefinite Integral in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050140/indefinite-integral-in-r).

The version of ryacas is 1.1.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

`Sym` is from the old version of **Ryacas**. With the current version, you can use `yac_str("Integrate(x) Sin(x)")`. If you want to use the old version, you can install the **Ryacas0** package.